# C#にてDataTemplateのデータを取得したい

Tags: c#

◆VIEWダイアログ

```
UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateA">
            <local:TemplateAView Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateB">
            <local:TemplateBView Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:TemplateSelector
        x:Key="MyTemplateSelector" 
        TemplateA="{StaticResource TemplateA}"
        TemplateB="{StaticResource TemplateB}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>


    ～～

    ComboBoxやTextBoxなどの入力部品

    <ContentControl x:Name="templateSelector"
        Content="{Binding TemplateIndex}"
        ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}"/>

   ～～
    <Button Content="OK"
        Command="{Binding OKComamnd}"/>★①
```

◆VIEW　TemplateA
　ComboBoxやTextBoxなどの入力部品を配置
◆VIEW　TemplateB
　ComboBoxやTextBoxなどの入力部品を配置

◆VIEWMODEL　TemplateA
　VIEWにバインドするプロパティなどを宣言
◆VIEWMODEL　TemplateB
　VIEWにバインドするプロパティなどを宣言

◆VIEWMODEL

public DelegateCommand OKComamnd { get; set; }

コンストラクタ内でOKボタン押下時処理を追加

```
       this.OKComamnd = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                入力値を保存してダイアログを閉じる★②
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Excep = ex;
            }

        });
```

◆テンプレートのセレクタークラス
        public DataTemplate TemplateA { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate TemplateB { get; set; }

```
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        int value = (int)item;
        if (value == 0)
            return TemplateA;
        else if (value == 1)
            return TemplateB;
        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);

    }
```

コンボボックスなどの変更により、画面でTemplateA、TemplateBを切り替わるようになったのですが、
★①のOKボタンを押下した場合に、TemplateA、TemplateBの選択した値を保存したいと考えているのですが、
★②などで選択したTemplateAまたは、TemplateBの値を取得するにはどのような方法があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`templateSelector`という`ContentControl`の`Content`が`TemplateIndex`プロパティにバインドされており、`local:TemplateSelector`で`Content`の値によって`DataTemplate`を切り替えているということですよね？

でしたら`TemplateIndex`プロパティがビューモデル側に存在していると思いますので、単に

```
var value = this.TemplateSelector;
```

のようにアクセスできると思います。

---

なお`ContentControl.Content`に`int`を渡してしまうと`DataTemplate`の内部で意味のある処理をすることが難しくなります。`TemplateIndex`のかわりに適当なビューモデルを使用して

```
class HogeContentViewModel
{
    private readonly ParentViewModel _Parent;
    public HogeContentViewModel(ParentViewModel parent)
    {
        _Parent = parent;
    }
}

class FugaContentViewModel { }

class ParentViewModel 
{
    // 実際には変更通知を行う
    public object TemplateContent { get; set; } 
}
```

のように定義し、`TemplateContent`をバインドして

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
{
    if (item is HogeContentViewModel)
        return TemplateA;
    else if (item is FugaContentViewModel)
        return TemplateB;
    return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
}
```

のように実装すれば`ContentControl`内部で`DataContext`として各`ContentViewModel`が使用できますので、これを経由して`DataTemplate`とビューモデル層が相互作用できます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
「◆VIEWダイアログ」について名前を少し修正しました。

コンボボックスでTemplateA、TemplateBを選べるようになっており、
どちらを選んだかというのをContentControlのContentのTemplateIndexにバインドされています。
おっしゃるとおり、Contentの値によってDataTemplateを切り替えているということになります。

ビューモデル側にはどちらのTemplateを選択しているかのIndexは持っていますのでおっしゃる通り、
var value = this.TemplateIndex;
とすると取得ができるようでしたが、
DataTemplateとして切り替えできる「TemplateA」と「TemplateB」のプロパティを取得したいです。
（わかりにくい説明となってしまい申し訳ありません）

Comment: @kanko ビューモデルから直接`DataTemplate`を触りたいということでしょうか。はっきり言ってビューとビューモデルの役割分担が破綻しています。`DataTemplate`はインスタンス生成に特化したオブジェクトですのでVから注入したところでVMでできることなど殆どありませんよ。`DataTemplateSelector`を使用せずにVMのプロパティとして`DataTemplate`を公開した方がいくらかマシです。

通常の設計なら`TemplateIndex`でどちらのテンプレートが選択されているか判断できれば十分です。

Comment: pgrhoさま　コメントありがとうございます。TemplateIndexの代わりにビューモデルを…なるほどです。さっそく試してみたところ、実施したかったことができました。大変勉強になりました。MVVMの構成についてもっと勉強してみます。